# Retrofit parse JSON response from API when model is in "data" object

Tags: java, json, retrofit2

How can I parse this response without having to create a separate response class for each entity.

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 100,
    "first_name": "Michael",
    "last_name": "Blankenship"
  }
}
```

I would like to have a generic class that can reference the data object and then just specify what type of class that should be used to parse the response

Something like this:

```
@Get
Call<User> getUser();

@Get
Call<Status> getStatus();
```

Without having to have multiple response classes for each type

```java
public class UserResponse {
    User data;
}

public class User {
    String first_name;
    String last_name;
}

public class StatusResponse {
    Status data;
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is the problem with JSON structure . I have also faced the similar problem and the hard fix and right fix would be to ask server team remove data key .

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for this would create a generic class something like this

```
public class BaseResponseWrapper <T> {

    @SerializedName("data")
    private T data;

    public BaseResponseWrapper(){
        super();
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```